# What kind of formula would I use to get all possible outcomes?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, problem-solving

I am into a CCG, and I got a question come to mind "how many possible out comes are there for deck combinations?"

The game is broken into three: Main Character (6 cards available, only one deck), Draw Deck (176 cards available, up to three copies, 45-528 card deck), Problem Deck (35 cards available, up to 2 copies, 10-70 card deck).

I wan't to know how many combinations for each (such as 6 for main characters and 6 for all three parts at max, take one from the draw deck[527] then you have 529 for just the draw deck and 3,174 for all three parts), and don't care about the order they come in. I would like to take the formula to also find more likely combinations (i.e. playable) if at all possible.

Comment: If you want help, you need to describe the problem more clearly.   Do you just choose one of six cards for the Main Character?  Do the order of cards matter in the decks? How can the Problem Deck have 90 cards if there are only two each of 35?  Clearly we cannot help with playable unless that is defined.

Comment: Derp. First, "only one per deck or game" means one. So a combination of them would be 6, and not 55. Second, no. The order doesn't mater at all. Third, sorry, my bad. 70 cards for the the Problem Deck. Is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider each deck separately and multiply the number of options for each deck.  For the Draw Deck, each card can come in zero to three copies, so without the $45$ card minimum you would have $176^4=959512576$ possibilities.  The practical answer is that the choices less than $45$ cards will be a small fraction of this, so ignore it.  Similarly for the Problem Deck, without the $10$ card minimum you would have $35^3=42875$ choices, giving about $2.5\cdot 10^{14}$ choices.

Comment: So... is that the solution to find out 0-599 card deck? The equation being 6*(176^4)*(35^3)=~2,500,000,000,000,000. It's the best thing I have. But how to I find out what amount would be for a 56-599 card deck? Thanks for at lest letting me know this much. I don't have my own computer so it might be a day or two till I can see a reply. So if I don't reply fast. that's why. Oh and 2.5 quadrillion... O.O

Comment: You are a factor $100$ to high on the computation.  This includes all deck sizes from 1 card (the character) to $599$ together.  The power of $4$ on the draw deck is because you can have $0,1,2,3$ of each type of card.  The largest number will be around half that size.  Very few of them will be too small.

Comment: Okay then. Thanks. And I thought (10^#) was that many didgets backwards. Like with googol, googolplex, googolplexian, and a googolplexianth.